# Adding .js file

Tags: javascript

I've got problem with adding my load() function, when  I add it in  by the end of body it works, but when I try to load it from .js file it doesn't..

My .js file:

```
function toggleAttributes(checkbox, radios, attribute, attributeValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i += 1) {
    // If checkbox is checked, set the attribute and the attribute value. If not, remove the attribute
    checkbox.checked === true ? radios[i].setAttribute(attribute, attributeValue) : radios[i].removeAttribute(attribute);
  }
}

function toggleRadios(el, id) {
  var radiosSelector = `#${id} input[type='radio']`,
    container = document.getElementById(id),
    radios = document.querySelectorAll(radiosSelector);
  container.classList.toggle("hide");
  toggleAttributes(el, radios, "required", "");
}
var i;
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
var radio = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');

var alertTxt = [];

function save() {
  var saved = '';
  var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
  for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    localStorage.setItem(checkboxes[i].id, checkboxes[i].checked);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked === true) {
      saved += radios[i].id + ' (checked radiobutton)\n';
    }

    localStorage.setItem(radios[i].id, radios[i].checked);
  }
  alert(saved);
}

function load_() {
  for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = localStorage.getItem(checkboxes[i].id) === 'true' ? true : false;

    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      var container = '#' + checkboxes[i].dataset.target;
      document.querySelector(container).classList.toggle("hide");
      var radios = document.querySelectorAll('#' + checkboxes[i].dataset.target + ' input[type="radio"]');
      for (j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) {
        radios[j].checked = localStorage.getItem(radios[j].id) === 'true' ? true : false;
      }
    }
  }
}

(function() {
  load_();

})();
```

and I'm adding my .js file like that:

```
<script src = "JS/zamowienie.js"></script>
```

before body in my

So what's wrong with that? Why it works when I add my scripts in .html file, but when I'm loading it from .js file it doesn't works...

Comment: does it show any error on console when you load the page ?

Comment: if your JS gets executed before the DOM is rendered - it can not manipulate it. either place it all under a document ready event, or add that script tag just before your `</body>` tag.

Comment: still don't work... other functions works well, but not load

Comment: you should add the respective html too as others wont be able to help as they dont know about the html that is working with the js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the script file before `</body>` tag like below, I have uploaded your script into a file and loaded it via my domain, it won't run correctly due to the restrictions on stackoverflow for `localStorage` but it will show you the following exception which shows that it is loading the script file and calling the `load_()` function and error is thrown from the line `checkboxes[i].checked = localStorage.getItem(checkboxes[i].id) === 'true' ? true : false;`

> VM236 local.js:39 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the
>   'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and
>   lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.
>       at load_ (https://omaraslam.com/local.js:39:33)
>       at https://omaraslam.com/local.js:56:5
>       at https://omaraslam.com/local.js:58:3

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .hide {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Wybierz dania:
  </p>
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkGlowne" data-target="pierwsze" onclick="toggleRadios(this, 'pierwsze')">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkGlowne">Glowne</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkZupy" data-target="zupy" onclick="toggleRadios(this, 'zupy')">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkZupy">Zupy</label>
  </div>
  <p>
    Pierwsze dania:
  </p>
  <div id="pierwsze" class="hide">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="piers">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="piers">Pierś z kaczki</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="stek">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="stek">Stek z antrykotu</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="sandacz">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="sandacz">Sandacz</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="karas">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="karas">Karaś</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="zupy" class="hide">
    <p>
      Zupy:
    </p>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="rosol">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="rosol">Rosół z kaczki</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="zurek">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="zurek">Żurek</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="kokosowa">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="kokosowa">Zupa kokosowa</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="save" onclick="save()">


  <script src="https://omaraslam.com/local.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: :D haha no worries @Dr.Weiss